# one to many relationship with different types of child models

Tags: laravel

I have a `product` table. For every product, it allows user to store two different types of resources. They are "File Upload" and "External Resource".

For "File Upload", user is allowed to upload a file of any type.

For "External Resource", user is allowed to input an external resource URL.

I have `files` and `external_resources` table.

What kind of relationship should I use to connect them together? Morph?

Comment: Is there any attribute in product that determine the resource type ?

Comment: Morph would be the correct option if you want them in the same relationship, But I would keep them separated.

Comment: Since you have two tables they are two different relationships. Your title also says one-to-many so that kind of reinforces this option. Polymorphic could work but it's unclear how similar the two kinds of model are.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a polymorphic relationship,

First, your migration files should be like:

```
Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->morphs('resourceable');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::create('files', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('name');
    $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::create('external_resources', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('name');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Second, your `File` and `ExternalResource` Models should contain `morphMany` relation:

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->morphMany(Product::class, 'resourceable');
}
```

Third, When creating new product you should take care to the new structure for your table, while the `'resourceable'` field in the migration file converted to `resourceable_id` and `resourceable_type`.
So, when creating a product that have a resource from file type you should add `'App\Models\File'` to `resourceable_type` and `'App\Models\ExternalResources'` when product have an external resource.

Finally, you could call the relations like:

```
// returns the product resource 
Product::first()->resourceable()->get();

// returns all of the file's products
File::first()->products()->get();

// returns all of the external resource's products
File::first()->products()->get();
```

Comment: I'm sorry I might be unclear in my original post. This is a one-to-many relationship. A product can have many resources (i.e. files or external resources urls). With your above setup, this could only limit to a one-to-one relationship?